# How to send signals to a qt class from a not qt class?

Tags: qt

I created a qt class only to make gui and displayed the data on gui.

i didn't want to freeze the gui that's why i created another non_qt class to perform the operation so i made a object in the gui class of non_qt class and pass the parameter in that and started it in a new thread.

now after completing the operation i want to notify the gui class so it can display the results.

i also want to access the status bar of gui class so when non_qt class is performing the operation it can display some message on gui..

(i tried it with qt class but it didn't work that's why i created non_qt class..with non_qt class threading part is working fine but signal part is not working so i'm not able to notify the gui class).

so please help me out how to send signal to a qt class from a not qt class????

Comment: That's not possible, the sender has to be a QObject. "i tried it with qt class but it didn't work that's why i created non_qt class" What didn't work?

Comment: threading part was not working with qt class..actually first i tried it with qt class as u told it should be a QObject but with QObject sender it was showing some error in moc file which is generated at compile timewhen i removed Q_object threading is working but signal part is not working

Comment: Add more details about that error. moc at compile time doesn't know about (run-time) threading, so I don't see any issues that could arise at compile time.

Comment: I found the answer..i have to make a qt class and derive it from Qthread instead of using non qt class..
In that qt class i have to declare a signal to emit it when the operation is complete..i should write a connect function in gui class to catch that emitted signal and when the signal is emitted i can write the code of displaying the output in slot of that respective emitted signal..

Answer (score 3):

The signal is a concept that only applies to classes that derive from `QObject`.

If you want to trigger a slot, you don't need a signal. If the receiving object lives in the same thread (**and only then**), you can call the slot method on the reciving object directly.

For example, given an instance of a GUI object with a slot:

```
MainWindow * mainWindow;

class MainWindow : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
  Q_SLOT void setStatus(const QString &);
  ...
};
```

You can simply do:

```
// The assert is essential to prevent bad bugs. If it triggers,
// you must use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` instead.
Q_ASSERT(mainWindow->thread() == QThread::currentThread());
mainWindow->setStatus("Finished");
```

If the receiving object may live in another thread, or if you don't want to worry about threading issues, then you must use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`, as follows:

```
// This is always safe. No need for asserts.
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mainWindow, "setStatus",
                          Q_ARG(QString, "Finished"));
```

This overload of `invokeMethod` will correctly choose the connection type depending on whether the receiving object runs in the same thread. If the receiver is in the same thread, the call is a direct call. If it runs in another thread, the call will be converted to a `QMetaCallEvent` and posted to the receving object. This is thread-safe and doesn't require the receving object's `setStatus` method to be thread-safe.